# Django - extend User with Profile model during creation of user for account types

Tags: django

I've discovered from researching that the best way for me to create account types for users is a one-to-one model, which I have named `profile`. What is unclear and I am not finding a clear answer for is how I can create this at the same time as creating the user. I am using the default user model in django.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work, and is hacky trying to use a `get` method inside a `post`.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=password, username=email, email=email) 
user.save()
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
user.profile.account_type = 'User'
user.save()
```

If it is relevant, I am using a radio select in an html form for account types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply by:

```
from yourapp.models import Profile

user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=password, username=email, email=email)

profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, account_type='User')
```

Or you can use [post save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) signal to save profile. For example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance, account_type='User')
post_save.connect(post_save_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm going to try to implement the first one, as I want to determine their account type by their selection in the form, however that is giving me a `IntegrityError at /accounts/register
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_profile_user_id_key"` error, trying to debug now

Comment: I've debugged it, I had a residual code that decided to work partially after removing my faulty code causing a duplicate attempt to create a profile entry. Thanks for your help, the first method definitely worked for me!